# python: Creating a function that receives a global variable as parameter and tests if it is defined

Tags: python, function, global-variables, try-catch

I have the following problem: 
In a Python module, I have a few global variables and instead of the usual try - except for each one of them, I want to test if they are defined using one general function.
I thought of this:

```
def isDefined(variable):    
    try:
        variable
        return True        
    except NameError as error:        
        return False
```

but it does not work.
Does anyone have an idea how to do it? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you have to pass your variable in as a string - else it will always 
raise a NameError.

The `globals`built-in in python returns the module dictionary  - 
global variables are stored in it.

```
def is_defined(variable):
    return variable in globals()

tomato = 42

is_defined ("tomato")
```

(If for some reason you think you can't have your variable name as a string, add some more context information, so I can tune the answer accordingly.)

To set a global variable with a default value:

```
def set_var(variable, value=0):
     globals()[variable] = value
```

Comment: how do I get the name of the variable ?

Comment: what I want to do is to add 2 setters : one with a parameter, and a default setter. in the getter I want to test if the variable is defined. if it is not, it is set to default via the second setter.

Comment: How do you get the name of the variable depends on your code. globals().keys() will give you all variable names, but also all function and classes names on the module